# swift compiler generates different swiftdeps files when using the same XCode version and Swift version

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, compiler-optimization

I'm compiling swift source files on two different Macs. The **swift** source files are located in the same non-relative paths.

When XCode runs the `swiftc` command on these *swift* source files, the compiler is generating different *swiftdeps* files and different .o in DerivedData files as well (as a result). Both these Macs have the same exact specs/architecture.

Both the Macs have the same XCode version 7D175. Both the XCode Preferences are the same. The swift versions are also the same.

The command that is being run specifically is 

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc -incremental -module-name <module-name-here>`

Comment: You describe the observed behavior, but not how this behavior is a problem to you. It's unclear to me what you are trying to do here, but you generally cannot rely on the compiler to produce binary-identical output for identical source files even on the same machine.